# Shift Calendar - determine shift based on given pattern

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've spent hours and countless pages of notebook paper trying to figure this out.

What I need is to be able to figure out what shift is on duty for a given day without having to manually enter all of the shifts for each year.

Common shifts for fire departments is 24 on 48 off, but we work 48 on 96 off. So given a start day, say 9-23-17, as the first day of C shift following a pattern of CCAABB from that date, how can I figure out which shift is on duty? Time of shift change doesn't matter, I just need to know which shift is on each day.

I've been pulling my hair out working this from every angle I can think of but haven't found a solution.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just needing to calculate without using a database, PHP's DateTime function will accomplish the task:

```
// set this to the first day shift 'A' is on
$startShiftA = new DateTime('2017-09-23');

// set this to the day to find which shift is working
$dayToTest = new DateTime('2017-09-25');

$shiftOnDuty = array(
  '0' => 'A',
  '1' => 'A',
  '2' => 'B',
  '3' => 'B',
  '4' => 'C',
  '5' => 'C'
);

echo $shiftOnDuty[$dayToTest->diff($startShiftA)->format('%d')%6];
```

That last one liner is a bit of a mouthful, so step by step, this is what it does:

1. Find the difference in days: `$dayToTest->diff($startShiftA)->format('%d')`
2. Find the modulo (remainder of the difference in days divided by 6): `%6`
3. This yields a number in the range of [0-5].  [0-1] are shift A, [2-3] are shift B, and [4-5] are shift C.
4. Use this number as the index of `$shiftOnDuty`

Sample run:

```
php > // set this to the first day shift 'A' is on
php > $startShiftA = new DateTime('2017-09-23');
php > 
php > // set this to the day to find which shift is working
php > $dayToTest = new DateTime('2017-09-25');
php > 
php > $shiftOnDuty = array(
php (   '0' => 'A',
php (   '1' => 'A',
php (   '2' => 'B',
php (   '3' => 'B',
php (   '4' => 'C',
php (   '5' => 'C'
php ( );
php > 
php > echo $shiftOnDuty[$dayToTest->diff($startShiftA)->format('%d')%6];
B
php > $dayToTest = new DateTime('2017-09-27');
php > echo $shiftOnDuty[$dayToTest->diff($startShiftA)->format('%d')%6];
C
php > $dayToTest = new DateTime('2017-09-29');
php > echo $shiftOnDuty[$dayToTest->diff($startShiftA)->format('%d')%6];
A
php >
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use arithmetic.

Start by getting the day difference.  Then you want to determine which day into the shift you are.  For this use modulo arithmetic, often done with `%` or the `mod()` function:

```
select (case (current_date - '2017-09-23') % 6
            when 0 then 'C' when 1 then 'C'
            when 2 then 'A' when 3 then 'A'
            when 4 then 'B' when 5 then 'B'
        end) as shift
```

The exact functions depend on the database, but you should be able to implement this in any database.

Comment: Modulo arithmetic is what I was looking for. I had tried this, but after hours of pulling my hair out I had to stop. Thank you!!